# Populating custom field through jackson

Tags: java, datetime, jackson, objectmapper

I have a POJO as below:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CalendarData {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    // field to contain formatted date as per clients requirement - shud be mirror of "date"
    private String formattedDate;
    private long date;
    private String errorCode;
    private String subErrorCode;
}
```

Downstream service is only sending `date` field as epoch and i want to have the `formattedDate` populated in run time in given format.

I can always write a custom function to format the data, but want to understand is there any *native jackson way* or *custom setter* to do that.

Comment: You are probably wrong. In your Java program you neither want epoch milliseconds nor a formatted date string. Just like you use `int` for a whole number and not a string, you want to use `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant` for your date and time. You only want to format it into a string when presenting it to your user in your UI.

Comment: @OleV.V. this POJO is being used for precisely that sir. it belongs to a service which is a _bridge_ and upstream is _dumb_ by design. hence it does all the parsing and downstream is not in my control! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost doing it right. However having a `@JsonFormat`-Annotation on a `String` field does not make to much sense, because if it already is String, there is nothing to convert for Jackson anymore. You can just make both fields of type `Date` and the `@JsonFormat` annotation on the `formattedDate` field will serialize it into the proper JSON String representation, exactly in the format you specified in the `pattern`. Jackson will by default serialize all `java.util.Date` Object of an object it needs to serialize into the epoch milliseconds as a regular JSON number. So this would work for you. However, as both fields in the final JSON will refer to the exact same Date object it feels weird to have them both as fields of the `CalendarData` object. I would suggest you just give `CalendarData` a single field `date` and then create a getter method for the `formattedDate` field. Here is what this could look like. By default Jackson will pick up all  getter functions and serialize their returned data into the generated json object.

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CalendarData {

    CalendarData(final Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date getFormattedDate(){
        return this.date;
    };

    private Date date;
}
```

**UPDATE**
As you updated your question I also want to update my answer. I recommend to you the following (analogous to what I already explained above).

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CalendarData {

    private Date date;
    private String errorCode;
    private String subErrorCode;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    // field to contain formatted date as per clients requirement - shud be mirror of "date"
    private Date getFormattedDate(){
        return this.date;
    };
}
```

**Then in my main I tried it out**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        CalendarData data  = CalendarData.builder()
                .errorCode("23")
                .subErrorCode("42")
                .date(new Date())
                .build();

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
    }
```

Which perfectly prints out

```
{
    "date": 1676642216673,
    "errorCode": "23",
    "subErrorCode": "42",
    "formattedDate": "17/02/2023 13:56:56"
}
```

Comment: tried this out without custom constructor with implemented builder already. now field is missing. i am not at liberty to expose custom single param constructor.

Comment: just add the @Builder annotation to the constructor instead of on the class

Comment: ahh...ok..i got the confusion here, POJO i posted has minimalistic attributes mentioned. have updated the some more attribs. single param constructor wont solve! :)

Comment: Updated my answer without custom constructor

Comment: i missed this part completely where Jackson will parse it to string when sending data via api. such noob. thank u. accepted!

Comment: Using a proper date-time type for the field is a great step forward. I strongly recommend that you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed, confusing and error-prone to work with and long outdated. Use for example `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).